Generate ECDH Certificate with OpenSSL
Is it possible to generate a certificate signing request in OpenSSL that has the restricted key algorithm:
id-ECDH (oid: 1.3.132.1.12)
as defined in RFC5480.
Every attempt I have made to generate a key, results in the unrestricted algorithm (id-ecPublicKey) being selected.
